# writing a large file to disk blocks celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

In my celery worker, there is a task that writes files to disk, sometimes the files are very large and at the time of writing a large file, the worker freezes and does not perform other tasks.
To write files, use pyexcelerate.
I run the worker with the

```
celery worker -A app -c 5 -P gevent
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What have you tried so far, what is your desired outcome? Create a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The "problem" is the concurrency type you use. Since you use gevent, you need to code your tasks properly, so they do not BLOCK the main thread (the worker). Try to use the default (prefork) concurrency and you will see that it works fine.